# What is the meaning of "rest in peace" ("RIP")?

Tags: prayer, new-testament, death, intercession, funeral

According to the New Testament of the Holy Bible, what is the interpretation of the phrase "may his/her soul rest in peace. RIP"?

Comment: RIP stands for *requiescat in pace*, which is a Latin sentence meaning "May he/she/it rest in peace." As far as I know, it does not appear in Scripture.

Comment: I answered a question on [Stack Exchange - English Language  Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/595031/259840) recently about 'died in peace' - which is in the English bible, Jeremiah 34:5. But 'rest in peace' is not. Up-voted +1. The expression prevalent in the Hebrew scriptures is 'rested with his fathers'.

Comment: It’s a saying that indicates soul sleep adherents are correct.  No continuation of consciousness after the body dies.

Comment: @User14, I don't think that's necessarily the case. In particular, the use of the phrase "*eternal* rest" (n.b. GratefulDisciple's [answer](/a/93074/53502)) implies that what those who are Saved experience after the Resurrection is "rest". To my knowledge, no one argues for *eternal* unconsciousness for those who are Saved.

Comment: @User14 I consider sitting to be a form of rest for myself. [Latin-English dot com](https://www.latin-english.com/word/37410/requiesco-requiescere-requievi-requietus/) renders the possible translations for requiesco (the root word) as 1. end 2. quiet down 3. rest. Compare this with Latin results for searching the word sleep, the top verb is [dormio](https://www.latin-english.com/word/34542/dormio-dormire-dormivi-dormitus/), not requiesco.

Comment: I feel like asking for biblical support is a wrong approach here. AFAIK, the origin of this phrase is Catholic (sounds most reasonable given that RIP stands for "requiescat in pace", a Latin phrase), and since most "biblical" sources deny existence of Purgatory (especially if their Bibles don't include books of Maccabees), the answers will be incomplete.

Comment: @Matthew John 11:11-14.

Comment: @User14, I don't understand your point? I'm not saying "soul sleep" isn't a correct view, I'm saying I don't think that's the rest to which RIP refers. Are you saying that the state of believers *after* the Resurrection will not be one of rest?

Comment: @Matthew I’m saying the rest in Rest In Peace is soul sleep.

Comment: @User14, and I'm saying it isn't. Certainly the "rest" mentioned in requiems, which are likely associated with the origin of "RIP", is *eternal* rest ("*requiem **aeternam** dona eis, Domine*"), which is not compatible with being the rest of soul sleep... unless you claim those that fall asleep in Christ never wake up!

Comment: @Matthew the phrase Rest In Peace has always referred to soul sleeping and the promise resurrected to life refers to awakening from death/sleep.  I’ve VTC’d this question as opinion based as our interchange demonstrates.

Comment: @User14, that does sound very much like *your* opinion, yes. If you are able to back that up at all, I encourage you to do so in the form of an Answer. (For my side, I'll refer you to the accepted answer.)

Comment: Yes, Rest In Peace is soul sleep. See my answer and also the other accepted answer Here.https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/56349/are-the-souls-of-revelation-69-11-awake-and-yet-still-awaiting-the-resurrecti

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RIP stands for *requiescat in pace*, which means "may he/she rest in peace".

Psalm 4, Verse 8 is

> *In pace in idipsum, dormiam et requiescam*

which means

> In peace together, I will sleep and rest

RIP is a shift of this from the first to the third person. A simple prayer that the deceased will now find peace after the tribulations of life on earth.

This verse is also traditionally used as the first prayer at the tomb/grave of a Catholic funeral.

There's no other similar phrase in the Bible, neither Old nor New Testament.

Comment: The verse (Psalm 4:8) says: "I will both lay me down in peace, and sleep: for thou, LORD, only makest me dwell in safety."  This addresses ordinary sleep, not death, and with the Hebrew use of "both" (יַחְדָּו֮) it is linking two separate actions; i.e. it may well mean that one is able to sleep because there is peace.  While this may be the nearest to a Biblical basis for "RIP" that one can find, it is still not a basis for it.

Comment: @Biblasia the RIP phrase is Catholic in origin, and this verse is used in Catholic liturgy very clearly in the context of death (literally as you are burying the body). As liturgy and theology was all conducted in Latin, that is where you have to look.

Comment: Catholic funeral mass template  reference link : https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.catholic.org.au/acbc-media/downloads/all-downloads/organisations-1/national-network-for-disability-and-spirituality-1/celebrating-the-sacramental-life-from-birth-to-death/2068-catholic-funeral-mass-template/file&ved=2ahUKEwiWjrTKqPH6AhUQg2MGHfFcBAIQFnoECDgQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3AaFhVeeOIeu1mbsS_F8L9

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar that doesn't have the liturgy at the grave, which is where this verse is used.

Answer (score 5):

#### The traditional use

The [*wikipedia* article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rest_in_peace) traces the phrase "requiescat in pace" ("may he/she rest in peace") to tombstone inscriptions as early as the 5th century.

Up to the Reformation, most Christian groups would offer prayers for the dead in connection with the belief of the [communion of saints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communion_of_saints) (part of the [Apostle's creed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostles%27_Creed)) which refers to the spiritual union of the living and the dead but excluding the damned. See [*wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prayer_for_the_dead#Christianity) on how different groups do this.

In [Catholic funeral mass](https://www.catholic.org.au/acbc-media/downloads/all-downloads/organisations-1/national-network-for-disability-and-spirituality-1/celebrating-the-sacramental-life-from-birth-to-death/2068-catholic-funeral-mass-template/file), the entrance antiphon has the following words as a prayer:

> Eternal rest grant unto them, O Lord, and let perpetual light shine upon them.

An example of this text set to music is the Introit of Mozart's Requiem (see [text](http://manlywarringahchoir.org.au/files/2011/01/English-Translation-of-Mozart-Requiem.pdf), [sample performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54h8TxJyNy0), minute 1:42).  The music text (in Latin) is the same:

> Requiem ætérnam dona eis, Dómine, et lux perpétua lúceat eis.

#### Is it Biblical to pray for the dead?

While I agree with the *GotQuestions* article [Is it biblical to say ‘rest in peace’ (RIP) in regards to someone who has died?](https://www.gotquestions.org/rest-in-peace-RIP.html) that it is *NOT* Biblical to say that *all* people who die ***WILL*** rest in peace, I agree with @jaredad7's comment that

> RIP stands for *requiescat in pace*, which means ***may*** he/she/it rest in peace. Requiescat is in the subjunctive mood. This is a saying **wishing someone to rest in peace, and that is biblical**. We should hope and pray for everyone to rest in peace.

Christian groups that continue the early church's understanding of the communion of saints will say that the practice is Biblical, some appealing to a plausible interpretation that Onesiphorus whom Paul prayed on behalf of ([2 Tim 1:16-18](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Timothy%201%3A16-18&version=ESV)) had died. While some groups say that the dead's fate is sealed upon death (making our prayers for them useless), other groups pray for the saved to increase in love, as taught in the catechism in the 1979 Anglican Book of Common Prayer:

> We pray for (the dead), because we still hold them in our love, and because we trust that in God's presence those who have chosen to serve him will grow in his love, until they see him as he is.

#### How about the dead's *actual* rest / peace?

What's the Biblical support that at least some believers will **actually** die in peace?  I think **[Heb 4:1-3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews%204&version=NLT) makes it clear that believers who die in Christ can be said to enter God's rest**:

> God’s promise of entering his rest still stands, so we ought to tremble with fear that some of you might fail to experience it. For this good news—that God has prepared this rest—has been announced to us just as it was to them. But it did them no good because they didn’t share the faith of those who listened to God. For only we who believe can enter his rest. As for the others, God said,
>
> “In my anger I took an oath: ‘They will never enter my place of rest,’” [Ps 95:11]
>
> even though this rest has been ready since he made the world.

Especially for those who *also* suffer greatly because of war or because of defending Christ, it will also be meaningful to say that they now "rest in peace" as they have been freed from their earthly torments.

Comment: "Dona eis pacem" ("give them peace") appears in some [requiem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requiem) texts, while "requiem aeternam dona eis, Domine" ("give them eternal rest, Lord") provides the other half. When the two thoughts were first combined, I couldn't say. 

Comment: RIP stands for *requiescat in pace*, which means *may* he/she/it rest in peace. Requiescat is in the subjunctive mood. This is a saying wishing someone to rest in peace, and that is biblical. We should hope and pray for everyone to rest in peace.

Comment: @jaredad7 Thanks!  I incorporated your comment into my answer.

Comment: The *GotQuestions* article you cite also specifically says "praying for the dead is unbiblical". How do you reconcile this versus the comment "wishing someone to rest in peace...is biblical. We should hope and pray for everyone to rest in peace"?

Comment: @nanoman That *GotQuestions* article represents the Protestant Reformed position, but several other Protestants groups and most groups from the early church to the Reformation allow prayers on behalf of the dead (see [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prayer_for_the_dead#Christianity)).  Majority seems to allow, and NT support from 2 Tim 1:16-18 is possible.

Answer (score 4):

The only Greek scripture verse that contains both "soul" and "peace" is:

> Now may the God of **peace** Himself sanctify you completely; and may your whole spirit, **soul**, and body be preserved blameless at the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ.
> — 1 Thessalonians 5:23

And even this one scripture has nothing to do with death.

"RIP" and "Rest In Peace" come from the Latin phrase "Requiescat In Pace", perhaps dating back to the 3<sup>rd</sup> century.

Like many other expressions:

- God works in mysterious ways.
- Cleanliness is next to godliness.
- God helps those who help themselves.
- The Seven Deadly Sins.
- Love the sinner. Hate the sin.

it is not from the Bible.

Comment: Thanks. You meant to say there is no plasms by any Saints regarding "May his soul rest in peace". Or "May her soul rest in peace" mentioned in the new testament of the Holy Bible?

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar, there is only one verse in all of the New Testament that contains both of those words.

Comment: Thanks. Now may the God of peace Himself sanctify you completely; and may your whole spirit, soul, and body be preserved blameless at the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ.
— 1 Thessalonians 5:23. This is a psalm which contains some words regarding resting in peace.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Thessalonians+5%3A23.+&sxsrf=ALiCzsY03M1S1vu_-rnxiK7AcQkgdLo1FQ%3A1666031457150&source=hp&ei=YZ9NY92qBrOeseMPhamGaA&oq=Thessalonians+5%3A23.+&gs_lcp=ChFtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1ocBADOgcIIxDqAhAnOg0ILhDHARCvARDqAhAnUMIVWJU5YNdKaABwAHgAgAH3AogB5xGSAQcwLjcuMi4ymAEAoAECoAEBsAEP&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-hp

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Epistle_to_the_Thessalonians

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar says "*This is a psalm which contains some words regarding resting in peace.*".  It is the same verse I quoted, but in it, "peace" describes God, and does not relate directly to "soul". ¶ (Note that it isn't a "psalm" though. A psalm is something meant to be sung, typically to harp music.)

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, the word *****rest***** in the New Testament is something each believer in Jesus Christ can experience, **this side** of the grave! The writer to the Hebrews addresses the concept of rest in Chapter 4. He posits that only those believers in Jesus Christ who are faithfully obedient to the Lord will enter into rest.

In other words, the promise of entering into God's rest was applicable not only to the Israelites as they journeyed toward the land of promise, but it is also applicable to believers under the New Covenant, from Christ's resurrection in the first century to the 21st century and beyond.

That rest is experienced by faithfully-obedient believers in Jesus as a surcease of striving to earn God's favor. Through Christ's death, burial, and resurrection, he alone earned the right to offer that rest to all who believe. Believers experience that rest in God's undeserved and unearned favor. We call that grace.

As for "resting in peace" (frequently abbreviated RIP), that phrase is not biblical in origin. The surcease of striving--in a general sense--certainly ends for all people--believers and unbelievers alike--when they die, but for the unbelievers who failed to enter that rest while alive, the afterlife will be anything **but** peaceful. The parable of Lazarus and the rich man makes this abundantly clear.

> “There was a rich man who was dressed in purple and fine linen and
> lived in luxury every day. 20 At his gate was laid a beggar named
> Lazarus, covered with sores 21 and longing to eat what fell from the
> rich man’s table. Even the dogs came and licked his sores.
> "The time came when the beggar died and the angels carried him to
> Abraham’s side. The rich man also died and was buried. In Hades,
> where he was in torment, he looked up and saw Abraham far away, with
> Lazarus by his side. So he called to him, ‘Father Abraham, have
> pity on me and send Lazarus to dip the tip of his finger in water and
> cool my tongue, because **I am in agony in this fire**.’

> “But Abraham replied, ‘Son, remember that in your lifetime you
> received your good things, while Lazarus received bad things, but now
> he is comforted here and **you are in agony**. And besides all this,
> between us and you a great chasm has been set in place, so that those
> who want to go from here to you cannot, nor can anyone cross over from
> there to us.’ “He answered, ‘Then I beg you, father, send Lazarus to my family,
> for I have five brothers. Let him warn them, so that they will not
> also come to **this place of torment**.’

> “Abraham replied, ‘They have Moses and the Prophets; let them
> listen to them.’ “‘No, father Abraham,’ he said, ‘but if someone from the dead goes
> to them, they will repent.’ “He said to him, ‘If they do not listen to Moses and
> the Prophets, they will not be convinced even if someone rises from the dead’” (Luke 16:19-31 NIV, my bolding).